# Why is $ date still displaying EST when /etc/localtime is symlinked to /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT?

Tags: centos, timezone, date

I'm having a problem setting the date on my server...

```
$ ls -la /etc | grep localtime
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  23 Mar 6  12:07 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT
```

For some reason, although the time **17:31:06** is GMT, the timezone suffix is EST...

```
$ date
Tue Mar  6 17:31:06 EST 2012
```

And the hardware clock is also messed up - **10:32:12** isn't EST:

```
$ hwclock --show
Tue 06 Mar 2012 10:32:12 PM EST  -0.000276 seconds
```

If I set the hwclock to the system time or localtime, it sets it incorrectly:

```
$ hwclock --localtime
Tue 06 Mar 2012 10:34:22 PM EST  -0.000190 seconds
$ date
Tue Mar  6 17:34:24 EST 2012
```

Any idea what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using ntp, or did you set all of this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was setting the hwclock to the system time and vice versa (which I was fiddling around with) actually modified the timezone files in /usr/share/zoneinfo. I had to copy fresh zoneinfo files from another server.

So all I can say is DON'T play with setting the system clock to the hardware clock and vice versa (`hwclock --hctosys`, `hwclock --systohc`) unless you know what you're doing!

Answer (score 6):

Three Simple Rules for Not Going Insane When Dealing With Time:

---

First: You're running Unix (and presumably NTP): ***Make sure you have set your system's BIOS/Hardware clock to UTC***.
The absolute last thing you need is your hardware (BIOS) clock fighting with Unix over whose timezone is right and when daylight saving time begins/ends.  Setting your hardware clock to UTC makes life much easier.

---

Second: When you change the system-wide time zone you sometimes need to log out and log back in again for the system to understand what happened.  Generally I suggest rebooting - this ensures every part of the OS has been kicked in the head and understands what has happened.
You don't want cron still running in US/Eastern time when you've changed the machine's timezone to Hawaii.

---

Third: If you user account still has a messed-up idea of the time zone something is probably setting the `TZ` environment variable -- double-check your `.profile` and shell rc files.
Unix doesn't assume that every user on the system is in the local time zone, so it lets you override on a per-user (or per-shell) level.  This is very useful if your system is running on (e.g.) US/Eastern time and you have users logging in from Japan - People like the time their system reports to match the clock on their wall :)

Comment: Don't forget `/etc/sysconfig/clock`, too. (Or, will that be updated on reboot from /etc/localtime?)

Comment: ...Because there are so many other worthy things you can go insane over besides dealing with time...

Comment: @AaronCopley My systems have no such file (if you use the CentOS tools to change the timezone that should be updated appropriately -- I'm not sure if it's tied to `/etc/localtime`, but if it's not let's add one more non-standard implementation to the litany reasons I despise Linux :)

Comment: @voretaq7 Not sure why your hosts don't have it. Very weird! Notice particularly, "ZONE=". http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-clock.html It's used by system-config-date so not necessary for actually changing the time, but should probably be of the same value if it exists.

Comment: @AaronCopley Probably because my hosts aren't CentOS (Everything's FreeBSD, with a few Debian/Ubuntu machines laying around that I'm trying to kill, and Debian Don't Do That `/etc/sysconfig` Stuff :)  On a redhat box though I would definitely use the `system-config-date` tool to be sure to catch *all* the places the system might be tucking timezone data

Comment: Followed all your advice and the hwclock and date command still return different times and neither of them are UTC. :(